# Pthread not executing function

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads, posix

i have been trying to figure out why a thread that i created in C, using pthread library is not executing the fucntion that pthread_create recieves.

Here is the code:

```
    void* escucharCPUs (void* arg){
     t_Escucha* cpu= (t_Escucha*) arg; 
     listen(cpu->servidor,cpu->cantConexiones);
     printf("estoy esperando CPUs");
     t_CPU* newCPU=malloc(sizeof(t_CPU));
     while(1){
      int cliente2 = recibirCliente(cpu->servidor);
      printf("Recibí una conexión en %d!!\n", cliente2);
      inicializarCPU(newCPU);
      list_add(listaCPUs,newCPU);
     }
    }
    //This is the function that pthread_create recieves.

    typedef struct{
     int servidor;
     int cantConexiones;
    }t_Escucha;

    //This one above is an auxiliar function for networking, I put it as extra info.

    //THIS GOES INSIDE THE MAIN
    t_Escucha* CPU;
    CPU=malloc(sizeof(t_Escucha));

    //And, here is the thread creation
    pthread_t hiloEscuchaCPUs;
    pthread_attr_init(&atributo);
    pthread_attr_setdetachstate(&atributo,PTHREAD_CREATE_DETACHED);
    t2=pthread_create(&hiloEscuchaCPUs,&atributo,escucharCPUs,(void*)CPU);
    //Is inside the main too
```

The result is, that the pthread_create acts like if it hasn't anything to do.

We(My entire working team) dont know what is going wrong there.

Anything that you propose will be helpful, Thank you!!

Comment: What did you expect to happen? What actually happened?

Comment: Please report what you directly observe. "Log mssages don't come out" is good. "Thread does not execute function" is not so good, there's no easy way to verify this.

Comment: How do you know the function is getting executed? Add more printfs. Attach the process to gdb and add a break for your thread function and check.

Comment: Please show a [mcve]. My guess is that the main thread is exiting without waiting for the child threads to complete. But since you have only shown partial code we cannot determine for sure.

Comment: Probably you have an [UB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) with first called function in task: `listen(cpu->servidor,cpu->cantConexiones);` CPU points to a `malloc`-ated **_not initialized_** memory.

Comment: Since you oh so wisely decide to `pthread_create()` a detached thread, how does the main thread avoid exiting before the created thread has finished its work?

Comment: @EOF , that's the point, how the f*** can i do that? it's driving me crazy

Comment: @hernang94: Theoretically, you can avoid `return`ing or `exit()`ing from `main()`, instead `pthread_exit()`ing in the main thread. Practically this is nonsense and you should do the sane thing and create joinable threads and `pthread_join()` with all threads before `return`ing or `exit()`ing from `main()`.

Answer (score 0):

To flush `stdout` (which is used by `printf()`) suffix each "string" by a new-line like this

```
   printf("estoy esperando CPUs\n");
```

Debug logging should go to `stderr` using `fprintf(stderr, ...)`. `stderr` isn't buffered as `stdout` is.